# Is it possible to pan/zoom cameras with php or js?

Tags: javascript, php, camera, ip

Can't find a similar question asked before.

I don't like the dvr that controls the ip camera.

I would like to make my own as a website though with php/js etc, is it possible? Could you point me in the right direction?

I know android apps can do it, there could be a a way...

Thank you

Comment: It is theoretically possible, but this isn't what StackOverflow is about. This place is for actual code problems (where you have code with errors or faulty behavior). Find out if your camera has an API and then come back if you have actual code issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it depends on the camera.

Some of them have proprietary protocols. If you reverse-engineer the protocol, you can implement your own control.

Many are using standards, like ONVIF, which is delivered over http(s). [Here you have PHP implementation](https://github.com/ltoscano/ponvif) and [NodeJS](https://github.com/agsh/onvif).

Even if possible, I don't recommend directly communicating with them from client side as you will need to expose credentials. After all, it is high security risk to let client-side devices reaching the cameras directly, at least VLAN separation is recommended.